# Why do I get 403 error only on certain apis on SendGrid Api v3?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am experiencing a strange problem on using SendGrid APIs.
Basically, there are certain API calls that I can perform, and some other returns a 403 error.

I can send single emails :

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
    $email->setFrom("myfrom@myurl.net", "NAMEFROM");
    $email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
    $email->addTo("myfrom@myurl.net", "NAMEFROM");
    $email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
    $email->addContent(
        "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
    );
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
```

But I am not able to send massive emails as campaigns:

```
$request_body = json_decode('{
        "id": <DATA HIDDEN>,
        "title": "May Newsletter",
        "subject": "New Products for Summer!",
        "sender_id": <DATA HIDDEN>,
        "list_ids": [
            "<DATA HIDDEN>"
        ],
        "html_content": "<html><head><title></title></head><body><p>Check out our summer line!</p></body></html>",
        "plain_content": "Check out our summer line!",
    }');
    $sg = new SendGrid(config('services.extra.SENDGRID_API_KEY')); 
    $response = $sg->client->campaigns()->post($request_body);
```

This call returns 403, "message":"access forbidden". Without any other indication.

Even the API Calls that follow :

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/senders/<data hidden>
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/senders
```

return 403.

I have a free plan and a verified email address (the "from address").
All the tokens I have generated have the "full" permission set.

I haven't read anything about the accessibility of an API regarding the price plan (free/paid) in the docs, but still, I wonder if anybody knows anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When i create the API key, it creates it with quite restricted permissions.  You then need to go and enable the permissions on the key.   I was getting 403 errors consistently, and when I finally added the permissions for the part of the API I was using, they started working.

Answer (score 0):

The Email API and Marketing Campaigns are two different products (see the [two different tabs on the pricing page](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/)). You can use both within one account, you just need to activate both products. I think you need to go to your [account settings and activate the Marketing Campaigns product](https://app.sendgrid.com/account/products) and then your API requests will succeed.

Comment: Hi philnash, thank you for reaching out. 
In the "account settings page", the "Marketing Campaigns Plans - free" is already marked as "my current plan" - together with "Email API". They both appear in the tab "Your products".
Still, I have the problem ;-(

Comment: Probably best to reach out to [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) then.